# Delete old nodes and relationships with Cypher in Neo4j 1.9

Tags: neo4j, cypher, nodes, relationships

I am using Neo4j 1.9 M03 in HA mode, my challenge is to remove all nodes and relationships as well as indices that are older than a certain date.

For this I created a property for nodes and relationships. The property is a datestamp in the "YYMMDD" format.

I'm trying to use the following Cypher query to perform the operation mentioned above:

```
START n0=node(0), nx=node(*) 
MATCH n0-[r0?]-(), nx-[rx?]-() 
WHERE nx <> n0 AND HAS (nx.datestamp) AND nx.datestamp <= yyyymmdd 
OR HAS (rx.datestamp) AND rx.datestamp <= yyyymmdd
DELETE r0,rx,nx
```

This query is not performing the operation I desire.
What can I be doing wrong here?

Comment: Is your date a String?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
START rx=rel(*)
WHERE HAS (rx.datestamp) AND rx.datestamp <= yyyymmdd
DELETE rx;
```

You have to make sure that the nodes you want to delete don't have any relationships left, either filter those out or you delete those additionally

```
START nx=node(*)
WHERE HAS (nx.datestamp) AND nx.datestamp <= yyyymmdd
AND NOT((nx)--())
DELETE nx;
```

Comment: Many Thanks Michael. However, the space occupied in Neo4j database remains the same. Does nodes and relationships are even being removed? In Neo4j web admin I run Neo4j Cypher query to count all nodes and relationships deleted that are older than some datestamp and the query result is 0 nodes and/or 0 relationships.

Comment: Michael the node/relationship properties wasn't deleted with this cypher query right? How can I delete also node/relationship properties? The metric "database disk usage" keeps on increasing even after removing nodes/relationships. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one

```
START n=node(*) 
MATCH n-[r?]-() 
WHERE  (n.datestamp? <= yyyymmdd AND r.datestamp? <= yyyymmdd) 
DELETE r,n
```

Comment: Seems fine but the metric "database disk usage" keeps on increasing even after removing nodes/relationships...