# (neo4j) Is it possible to remove a Node from an Index via Cypher, REST or Webadmin console?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Referencing these 2 stackoverflow questions:

1. [Delete old nodes and relationships with Cypher in Neo4j 1.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034105/delete-old-nodes-and-relationships-with-cypher-in-neo4j-1-9)
2. [Deleting indexed nodes in Neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587025/deleting-indexed-nodes-in-neo4j)

I have a graph where a number of Nodes are incorrectly in Indexes. I think this happened because Nodes were deleted using Cypher or using the `Delete` button on the Webadmin console, without realising that this would NOT also delete the Node from any Indexes that it was in.

The result is that these Nodes are now being returned incorrectly for queries which use those Indexes for the start Nodes.

Is it possible to remove a Node from an Index using Cypher, REST API or the Webadmin console?

Or am I going to have to write some custom Java (I'm using embedded mode) which does something like:

```
Iterable<Node> offendingNodes;
Iterable<Index<Node>> allIndexes;
for(Node offendingNode : offendingNodes) {
    for(Index<Node> index : allIndexes) {
        index.remove(offendingNode);
    }
}
// Now re-index offendingNodes correctly
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can delete nodes from indexes with REST like so:

DELETE http://[address]:[port]db/data/index/node/[indexname]/[nodeid]

[REST API - Indexes](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-indexes.html)

Comment: Using the REST API via the Webadmin, when I issue this command, the response is `204 No Content`. Is that correct / expected?

Comment: In addition, I'm finding that the specified Nodes are still to be found via the Index tried. In other words, it hasn't worked :-(

Comment: 204 No Content should be te correct response. Can you setup the case in an accessible console?

Comment: Do you mean open up the server on a public URL? I'm not going to be able to do that I'm afraid. The best I'll be able to do is post commands tried, and the responses.
I'm using a Cypher query which isolates 11 nodes (out of millions) which should not be in that index (same result via neo4j-shell and webadmin) `START p=node:profiles('profile_url:*') WHERE NOT(HAS(p.type)) RETURN ID(p)`. Then executing a REST command such as `DELETE /db/data/index/node/profiles/node/profiles/3339739` where `3339739` is one of the Node IDs returned. (same result via webadmin or command line 'resty').

Comment: AH! just saw that typo! Repeated `/node/profiles` - doh! Let me try again.

Comment: Nah didnt mean to open your server, just create a publicly visible isolated case. Anyway glad it worked out :D